# How to execute different classes in one class

Tags: java, class

I want to create a program that can do all the stuff from another code, depending on user input. Something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main_Programm1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String something = "something";
        String something2 = "something2";
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String action = userInput.next();
        if (action.equals(something)) {
            //here i want to execute all the code from class Main_Programm2
        } else if (action.equals(something2)) {
            //here i want to execute all the code from class Main_Programm3 and so on
        }
    }
}
```

How do i do it?

Comment: Read about Oops Concept.Constructor,Method calling etc

Comment: just call the method you need: `Main_Program2.method();`...

Comment: Import the both classes and call their main-method like Main_Programm2.main(args); This should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you've got it all done, only creates the Objects that you need ;-)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
// imports classes;

public class Main_Programm1 
{
  public static void main(String args[]) 
  {
    String something = "something";
    String something2 = "something2";
    Main_Programm main_prog;
    Main_Programm2 main_prog2;

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String action = userInput.next();
    if (action.equals(something)) 
    {
      main_prog = new Main_Programm();
      //.....
    } 
    else if (action.equals(something2)) 
    {
      main_prog2 = new Main_Programm2();
      //.....
    }
  }
}
```